# Xamarin needs reference to Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, dotnet-httpclient

I have created a new iPhone (iOs 9.3) app with Xamarin from within Visual Studio 2015 update 2. I have Xamarin beta channel on the mac (which has Xcode etc.)

I have this code:

```
using Windows.Web.Http;
...
private async void GetPois()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("http://onlinesource/json"));
}
```

and I get the error on the `GetAsync` I do not have the httpclient nuget installed, because it threw an error.

[image: add ref to assembly Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract]

already had `ModernHttpClient` nuget installed, but did not use it. @Andrii Krupka yes I also have `using System;`
I added `System.Net.Http` instead of `Windows` but now I have type or namespace could not be found.  added a reference to both system.net and system.net.http and now it works. next thing to solve is to disable ats. will mark this as answered by @SushiHangover thanks everyone!

Comment: Do you have `using System;` line in namespaces?

Comment: What error did you get when you tried to install httpclient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the namespace `System.Net.Http` instead of `Windows....`.

Then your `HttpClient` will work fine under iOS, assuming your have disable ATS since that is a non-secure HTTP link... ;-)

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("http://onlinesource/json"));
```

On a personal note: I greatly prefer `ModernHttpClient` @

https://github.com/paulcbetts/modernhttpclient

(Cross platform, PCL, cleaner, faster, able to leap buildings in a single request, etc...)

Comment: Yes, had to manually add some XML to disable ATS. It is just an internal test app. So not for the store. I use the `ModernHttpClient` now. Thank you for help and suggestions.

Comment: @JPHellemons No problem, Happy 'Xammie' Coding ;-)